# How to find the min form input

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I  tried to find the min and my code
not give me the min , what I  miss?

```
def hahaha(number):
lista=[]
while len(lista)<user:
    input_from_user=int(input())
    lista=lista+[input_from_user]
    for i in lista:
        b=lista[0]
        if b<i:
            i=b
return b
```

user=int(input("how many students"))
hahaha(user)

Comment: Formatting your code, reading the documentation of `min`, for starters.

Comment: You assign `b = lista[0]` and `b` is never assigned any other value, so of course the same value is always returned at the end...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve.  This function queries the user a predefined number of times and returns the minimum of the inputs that the user has entered. I haven't added any error capture features to keep it simple.

```
import math
def find_min_input(num_inputs):
    min_input = math.inf #initialize the minimum to infinity
    for i in range(num_inputs):
        input_from_user = int(input(f'You have {num_inputs - i} numbers left to enter.\nEnter a number: '))
        if input_from_user < min_input:
            min_input = input_from_user #update the minimum
    print(f'The minimum of the numbers you entered is: {min_input}')

#sample run:
find_min_input(3)

You have 3 numbers left to enter.
Enter a number: 5
You have 2 numbers left to enter.
Enter a number: 12
You have 1 numbers left to enter.
Enter a number: 8
The minimum of the numbers you entered is: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as the for loop:

```
# pick the first element as the smallest
smallest = lista[0]

# iterate over each remaining item in the list
for number in lista[1:]:

    # if this item is smaller than the smallest so far,
    # pick it as the new smallest number
    if number < smallest:
        smallest = number

print("The smallest item is", smallest)
```